# CSS3 - How to add a different color at a middle of a line without adding html elements

Tags: html, css

I have the next css rule for some div -

```
.somediv {
    background-color: #20b2aa;
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 7px;
}
```

Basically it's a blue line.

Now the thing that I'm trying to do is to make at the middle of it some area that will be let's say black.

Is that possible to do with only css rules and without adding any html elements?

Thanks for any kind of help

EDIT

Well what I want to do is -

=======black==========

the '=' - represent the blue area

Comment: The only thing you can do is adding `background-color:black;` and make the `border: solid 3px #20b2aa;`.

Comment: @azhpo - It's not the only thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra `:before` or `:after` :pseudo-elements, you can simply add `linear-gradient` instead of a single color.

```css
.somediv {
  background: linear-gradient(#20b2aa, #20b2aa 3px, black 3px, black 6px, #20b2aa 6px, #20b2aa 9px);
  cursor: row-resize;
  z-index: 800;
  height: 9px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  How would it know what part should be different?  There are special cases like first-letter.

Perhaps you can change the style from a background color to a background *image.*

Answer (score 0):

```
.somediv {
    background-color: #000000;
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 3px solid #20b2aa;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #20b2aa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: #20b2aa url('image.gif') repeat-x 0 3px;` where `image.gif` is 1×1 black pixel image. Or you can try [background gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#20b2aa+0,20b2aa+45,000000+50,20b2aa+55,20b2aa+100;Custom).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use pseudo-element [**:after**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```css
.somediv {
  background-color: #20b2aa;
  cursor: row-resize;
  z-index: 800;
  height: 20px;
}
.somediv:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Use linear gradient on background */
.somediv {
    background: linear-gradient(#20b2aa 0, #20b2aa 3px, black 3px, black 4px, #20b2aa 4px, #20b2aa 100%);
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 7px;
}

/** Use background and borders */
.somediv {
    border-top: solid 3px #20b2aa;         /* 3px border top */
    border-bottom: solid 3px #20b2aa;      /* 3px border bottom */
    background: black;
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 1px;                           /* 1px div height */
}
```

Check both solutions live at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbQWQa?editors=110)

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```css
.somediv {
    background-image: linear-gradient(blue 49%, red ,blue 51%);
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.somediv {
    background-color: #20b2aa;
    cursor: row-resize;
    z-index: 800;
    height: 7px;
}
.somediv:after
{
    content         : '';
    margin          : auto;
    display         : block;
    width           : 10px;
    height          : 7px;
    background      : black;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.This might provide an answer to the question.Little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand.